# bad FPS with android SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, frame-rate

I'm aware that there is alot of posts on this subject but non really helped me with my problem. Im fairly new to android programming and built my thread with the helt of a tutorial, the problem is that my emulator dosnt go over 15 fps and the program should run at 50 (FPS is initialized at 50). Here is the code from my thread:

```
    public class MainThread extends Thread {

private static final String TAG = MainThread.class.getSimpleName();

// desired fps
private final static int MAX_FPS = 50;
// maximum number of frames to be skipped
private final static int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
// the frame period
private final static int FRAME_PERIOD = 1000 / MAX_FPS;

/* Stuff for stats */
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##"); // 2 dp
// we'll be reading the stats every second
private final static int STAT_INTERVAL = 1000; // ms
// the average will be calculated by storing
// the last n FPSs
private final static int FPS_HISTORY_NR = 10;
// last time the status was stored
private long lastStatusStore = 0;
// the status time counter
private long statusIntervalTimer = 0l;
// number of frames skipped since the game started
private long totalFramesSkipped = 0l;
// number of frames skipped in a store cycle (1 sec)
private long framesSkippedPerStatCycle = 0l;

// number of rendered frames in an interval
private int frameCountPerStatCycle = 0;
private long totalFrameCount = 0l;
// the last FPS values
private double fpsStore[];
// the number of times the stat has been read
private long statsCount = 0;
// the average FPS since the game started
private double averageFps = 0.0;

// Surface holder that can access the physical surface
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
// The actual view that handles inputs
// and draws to the surface
private MainGamePanel gamePanel;

// flag to hold game state
private boolean running;

public void setRunning(boolean running) {
    this.running = running;
}

public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");
    // initialise timing elements for stat gathering
    initTimingElements();

    long beginTime; // the time when the cycle begun
    long timeDiff; // the time it took for the cycle to execute
    int sleepTime; // ms to sleep (<0 if we're behind)
    int framesSkipped; // number of frames being skipped

    sleepTime = 0;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        // try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing
        // in the surface
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                framesSkipped = 0; // resetting the frames skipped
                // update game state
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);
                // calculate how long did the cycle take
                timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                // calculate sleep time
                sleepTime = (int) (FRAME_PERIOD - timeDiff);

                if (sleepTime > 0) {
                    // if sleepTime > 0 we're OK
                    try {
                        // send the thread to sleep for a short period
                        // very useful for battery saving
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }

                while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
                    // we need to catch up
                    this.gamePanel.update(); // update without rendering
                    sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD; // add frame period to check
                                                // if in next frame
                    framesSkipped++;
                }

                if (framesSkipped > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Skipped:" + framesSkipped);
                }
                // for statistics
                framesSkippedPerStatCycle += framesSkipped;
                // calling the routine to store the gathered statistics
                storeStats();
            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        } // end finally
    }
}

/**
 * The statistics - it is called every cycle, it checks if time since last
 * store is greater than the statistics gathering period (1 sec) and if so
 * it calculates the FPS for the last period and stores it.
 * 
 * It tracks the number of frames per period. The number of frames since the
 * start of the period are summed up and the calculation takes part only if
 * the next period and the frame count is reset to 0.
 */
private void storeStats() {
    frameCountPerStatCycle++;
    totalFrameCount++;
    // assuming that the sleep works each call to storeStats
    // happens at 1000/FPS so we just add it up
    // statusIntervalTimer += FRAME_PERIOD;

    // check the actual time
    statusIntervalTimer += (System.currentTimeMillis() - statusIntervalTimer);

    if (statusIntervalTimer >= lastStatusStore + STAT_INTERVAL) {
        // calculate the actual frames pers status check interval
        double actualFps = (double) (frameCountPerStatCycle / (STAT_INTERVAL / 1000));

        // stores the latest fps in the array
        fpsStore[(int) statsCount % FPS_HISTORY_NR] = actualFps;

        // increase the number of times statistics was calculated
        statsCount++;

        double totalFps = 0.0;
        // sum up the stored fps values
        for (int i = 0; i < FPS_HISTORY_NR; i++) {
            totalFps += fpsStore[i];
        }

        // obtain the average
        if (statsCount < FPS_HISTORY_NR) {
            // in case of the first 10 triggers
            averageFps = totalFps / statsCount;
        } else {
            averageFps = totalFps / FPS_HISTORY_NR;
        }
        // saving the number of total frames skipped
        totalFramesSkipped += framesSkippedPerStatCycle;
        // resetting the counters after a status record (1 sec)
        framesSkippedPerStatCycle = 0;
        statusIntervalTimer = 0;
        frameCountPerStatCycle = 0;

        statusIntervalTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastStatusStore = statusIntervalTimer;
        // Log.d(TAG, "Average FPS:" + df.format(averageFps));
        gamePanel.setAvgFps("FPS: " + df.format(averageFps));
    }
}

private void initTimingElements() {
    // initialise timing elements
    fpsStore = new double[FPS_HISTORY_NR];
    for (int i = 0; i < FPS_HISTORY_NR; i++) {
        fpsStore[i] = 0.0;
    }
    Log.d(TAG + ".initTimingElements()",
            "Timing elements for stats initialised");
}
```

}

All my drawing method has is this:

```
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    happy.draw(canvas);
    // display fps
    displayFps(canvas, avgFps);
```

There is some updates in there aswell but thats just to get my sprite moving. If any1 can see a problem or has any tips PLEASE let me know. 
Thank you!
    }

Comment: You should test it on a device. The emulator can be.... well, bad at emulating, especially where performance comparisons are concerned.

Comment: the emulator isn't bad at emulating... It *is* emulating.  It isn't a simulator.  Geobits is right though, you cannot rely on performance testing in an emulator.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer :) I was thinking the same thing but just wanted to know if anything was wrong with my g-loop since im so new to this..

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on your emulator for performance benchmarking. While the emulator is good for checking the functionality and correctness of your app, it can take more (or less) time to do certain operations than a real device would. In perticular drawing operations seem to be longer on the emulator. I had a game run at 9-16 fps on the emulator while going 50+ on an old real device.

If your app/game still runs too slow on a real device you can profile your app (with TraceView for example) to see exactly what is taking up all your time and try to either optimize it or remove it (if possible).

Just as an extra tip: if possible try to have your surfaceView format be the same as all the resources that go on it, and try to prescale everything you can in advance (either at compile-time or at app startup/initialization phase), scaling and converting are expensive operations to do each frame.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows, you might try BlueStacks. Here are some of my results:

```
 *****************************************************
   ARM Emulator 2.4 GHz Core 2 Duo

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 06-Mar-2013 21.17

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+       2.66     3.97     3.29     1.61
  18000+       1.48     1.84     1.72     0.88
  36000+       0.82     0.95     0.87     0.46

      Screen Pixels 320 Wide 480 High


 *****************************************************
      BlueStacks Emulator on 3 GHz Phenom

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 06-Mar-2013 21.25

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+      41.72    42.02    32.90    20.72
  18000+      22.11    22.09    19.28    11.58
  36000+      11.16    11.14    10.35     5.89

      Screen Pixels 1024 Wide 600 High

 *****************************************************
  Samsung EXYNOS 5250 Dual 2.0 GHz Cortex-A15, Android 4.2.2
             Mali-T604 Quad Core GPU

 Android Java OpenGL Benchmark 09-Aug-2013 09.42

           --------- Frames Per Second --------
 Triangles WireFrame   Shaded  Shaded+ Textured

   9000+      39.13    41.52    32.19    27.25
  18000+      22.03    20.73    19.69    16.30
  36000+      12.24    12.23    10.75     8.68

      Screen Pixels 1920 Wide 1032 High
```